# AP doesn't work properly with D'link dgs switch

Tags: switch

I purchased D'Link (dgs 1210 28 ) rack switch to connect 4 AP with a router temporary (Network will extend soon).

After I plugged the Data server and the Router into the switch the lights became green but when I connect the AP's, all AP ports start flashing amber light and 2 of them without internet connection.

The previous switch was Cisco and all AP were connected without any problem.

What I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Configure them for your new infrastructure and equipment... Try factory resetting them and reading the instructions... Also, PLAN YOUR NETWORK! Draw it and write your important information like devices and their connections, the IPs on your network etc.

Comment: I've Set a static IP for each AP and reserved them, and also the dhcp is off in all AP cuz i get my IP's from the router. everything was working properly on cisco switch but on the new one I'm faceing some problems

Comment: You've set static IPs "and" reserved them? You need to give the APs IPs outside your router DHCP scope to prevent conflicts. Have you set the APs to use your router as their gateway and the same subnet?

Comment: DHCP pool start from 10 to 254 . The Ap is from 2 to 5

Comment: Have you configured the gateway addresses for the APs to point to the router?

Comment: yeah... Sure ,as I said , it was workig with cisco switch